# Multiselct product attribute is not beign added into collection filtering

Tags: magento-1, collection, multiselect-attribute

I have created a multi select attribute and assigned this to attribute set. Attribute is showing in product search results but I am unable to include this into product collection filtering as well as into **addAttributeToSelct** 
Here is the section I am using this attribute to filter the prodcut collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku','speciality','name'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('speciality', array('eq' => $speciality));
echo $collection->getSelect();
```

And in my browser I have the following result for select query

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`name` FROM `catalog_product_flat_3` AS `e` WHERE (e.status = 1)
```

Here are screen shot for the attribute configuration
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first look, I see two points that could help you :

1) It seems that you are using the `flat_catalog` feature. And, as your attribute `speciality` is set to be `Used in product listing`, you have to reindex `product_flat` index before to be able to retrieve it in your collection.

2) I think you should use `addAttributeToFilter` instead of `addFieldToFilter` too.

Comment: Thanks @julien-loizelet,  I was using flat_catalog on my store so by re-indexing  the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks. If you think it is a correct answer, please mark my answer as accepted answer : it may help future users.